what's the keyboard short cuts for `continue` button when debugging in vistual studio?
I have setup the keyboard shortcuts for step into and step over, but I didn't find the keyboard shortcuts for continue.
I'm using vs2022.
Does anyone know it? thanks!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

thanks, according to the documents and the comments from jesse, I have resolve it.

By default the continue button(commandDebug.Start) when debugging is F5.

F5 should let the debugger continue...

thanks, because I use another keyboard shortcuts, I can't know what's the command id of the old shortcuts. you did help me.
